# Flutter, not sure how to implement a PageRouteBuilder(), when using a WidgetBuilder to configure my routes

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: codGray,
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          WidgetBuilder builder;
          // Manage your route names here
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => ProviderPage();
              break;
            case '/chats':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => ChatProviderPage();
              break;
            case '/addPoll':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => AddPollPage();
              break;
            case '/friends':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => ProfileProviderPage();
              break;
            case '/settings':
              builder = (BuildContext context) => SettingsProviderPage();
              break;
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: builder,
            settings: settings,
          );
        },
      ),
}
```

This is a snippet of my project, I'm trying to implement custom animations when transitioning between pages, however since I'm routing using a custom navigator, which uses a WidgetBuilder, I'm not sure how to implement a custom PageRouteBuilder(), which uses the WidgetBuilder builder to transition between pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by directly return the `MaterialPageRoute` or `PageRouteBuilder` like this.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: codGray,
      body: Navigator(
        key: _navigatorKey,
        initialRoute: '/',
        onGenerateRoute: (RouteSettings settings) {
          switch (settings.name) {
            case '/':
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ProviderPage(),
                settings: settings,
              );
            case '/chats':
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (BuildContext context) => ChatProviderPage(),
                settings: settings,
              );
            case '/customTransition':
              return PageRouteBuilder(
                pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => Page(),
                transitionsBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation, child) {
                  return child;
                },
              );
            default:
              throw Exception('Invalid route: ${settings.name}');
          }
        },
      ),
}
```

Although you can refactor a lot of things here to make it more readable and maintainable

1. You can extract out this function given to `onGenerateRoute` argument in `Navigator` widget
2. Use constants for the routes. It makes it readable and less error-prone because of typos.
3. You can create extend `PageRouteBuilder` with your own class which takes a child argument of `Widget` type and rest all transition logic goes in that class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, got the code to work. Also how would the onGenerateRoute function work.

Comment: @AnshumanKomawar the `onGenerateRoute` argument expects a function that takes `RouteSettings` as an argument and returns `Route` object. Both `MaterialPageRoute` and `PageRouteBuilder` are inherited from `Route` class hence we returning a `Route` object here

Comment: Thanks a lot, will implement the onGenerateRoute method, I was also having some trouble regarding the custom navigator I'm using. I want to implement navigator.pop in another widget in regards to this same navigator, would you know how to implement this.